# Moving file from shared drive to SAS sever

Tags: linux, excel, sas, connection

Right now I have a SAS process that requires excel files that are saved on a shared drive. I manually move these files from the shared drive to the SAS server. Is there a way to move the files automatically through SAS or through PuTTY? I'm hoping to have to remove this manual step. My sas programs sit on the shared drive and run on the SAS server, so I have to think this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If it is shared drive your SAS server should see it. In your code you cen refer to those files using netowork path `\\share`.

Comment: There are options but it depends on your system set up. Are you working on Base SAS? Or SAS EG?

Comment: Hi @Reeza. I am using SAS EG. When I manually import the file I get this message in the SAS Code that is created:
   Generated on Tuesday, August 16, 2016 at 6:03:02 PM
   By task:     Import Data Wizard   
   Source file: G:\CREDIT\APPLICAT\Credit and Reward Goals Automated
   Process\dev\Client Data\SEP2016\Performance Summary Report
   Changes.xls
   Server:      Local File System   
   Output data: WORK.Performance_Summary_Report_Chang
   Server:      SASApp2

Comment: Note: In preparation for running the following code, the Import
   Data wizard has used internal routines to transfer the source data
   file from the local file system to SASApp2. There is no SAS code
   available to represent this action.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Copy custom task from Chris Hemidinger @ SAS to move files between server and desktop.

Unfortunately its not automatic and can't be included in your process flow.